# How to delete a line if string is the only thing on the line

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

How can I use sed or something else to delete a line only if the string I'm searching for is the only thing on the line?

Example output:

```
    device-address-binding: ?
    database-revision: 20
  -- Found 198 Objects 
  }, 
  { 
    object-identifier: (Analog Input, 1)
    object-type: ({  Analog Input  },)
    object-name: "CA-1 T EXT"
    descrip
```

I need to delete the lines containing "  }," but only on lines that have nothing else.
If I use sed to match and delete a line containing "  }," on the output above the line "object-type" would also get deleted.

It would be nice to search for "  },/n" but we all know sed doesnt work that way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is there is a space before `},`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` uses `$` for the line end:

```
sed '/^},$/ d'
```

`^` means the line beginning. You might also need to tolerate some whitespace around `},`.

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*},[[:space:]]*$/ d'
```

Comment: So if I get this right ^[[:space:]]* means anything that begins ^ with a range [] of space char [:space:] and nothing else * before the rest of the string. Do I get an A+ ?

Comment: I guess I could also simply use    sed '/^  },$/d'    since I know exactly how many spaces are before an after and it never changes.

Comment: A litter smaller `sed '/^ *}, *$/d' file`

Comment: I just tried what I and Raj suggested... doesnt work, turns out that last char on the line isnt really a space, its a linefeed which got translated into a space under windows' copy/paste

Comment: Ok so turns out even tough the one and only char after the comma in my string is a linefeed, which is supposedly stripped by SED's interpreter, I had to use [[:blank:]] to match the linefeed char before the end of line $ otherwise sed would'nt match it... weird. So im using this now    sed '/^  },[[:space:]]$/d'   thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 3):

No need for `sed`:

```
grep -vx }, file
```

Or to allow blanks:

```
grep -vx '[[:blank:]]*},[[:blank:]]*' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*},[[:blank:]]*$/d' file
```

Comment: Excellent, could you explain how it works? Im new to sed and I'd like to understand the search pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it many ways, here is a `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -ple 's#^\s*},\s*##' file
    device-address-binding: ?
    database-revision: 20
  -- Found 198 Objects 

  { 
    object-identifier: (Analog Input, 1)
    object-type: ({  Analog Input  },)
    object-name: "CA-1 T EXT"
    descrip
```